# Is there employment opportunities of becoming a pilot

Tags: flight-training

I am 18 years old and I want to become a pilot so bad .i got B grades in math and C grades in physics and geography.but my parents don't want me to be one since is hard to get employment of becoming a pilot.So am asking is there any employment opportunities of becoming a pilot

Comment: It's as hard as any other job which demands skills. The bad (or good depending on the point of view) thing is that to enter the club you need to have more than 100k ready to spend. If you manage to get into one of the cadet programs by CAE or L3, you will be at the top of the list for recruitment. One personal suggestion: the selection for being a pilot (with no previous experience) relies a lot on soft skills. At 18 humans are still young, get a degree in the meantime to improve your soft skills

Answer (score 2):

By the time you get your Commercial checkout (or ATP) or what ever your local jurisdiction requires you should have no issues finding a job just based on the numbers. There is a *growing shortage* of pilots and its no secret there are jobs available:

- [Pilot Shortage Is Real and Getting Worse](http://aviationweek.com/nbaa-2018/pilot-shortage-real-and-getting-worse)
- [The pilot shortage](https://www.flyingmag.com/pilot-shortage-business-aviation)
- [Cargo Airlines face pilot shortages](https://www.freightwaves.com/news/airfreight/cargo-airlines-face-pilot-shortages)
- [A 'Perfect Storm' Pilot Shortage Threatens Global Aviation](https://www.forbes.com/sites/marisagarcia/2018/07/27/a-perfect-storm-pilot-shortage-threatens-global-aviation-even-private-jets)

Answer (score 2):

Dave is absolutely correct in that there is an unprecedented shortage of crews.  A lot of it, in North America at least, is the effects of the Baby Boom demographic wave passing through the final stages.  Not enough young people learning to fly, too many pilots retiring, more people travelling than ever.

There has never been a employment picture for pilots like this. Never.  That said, it's still a long difficult road but with much higher chances of success than 20 or 30 years ago.

If you are the kind of person that drops what you are doing to watch airplanes fly overhead, anytime anywhere, then you should go for it because you are likely to stick it out.  Make a plan, figure out what to do and go step by step and don't let naysayers discourage you.

Try for whatever state sponsored programs are available; military or civilian.  If that doesn't work and if marks aren't top notch that may be the case, take the longer road.

You'll have to become employable and get a normal job to finance your flying, and to have a back up in place if it all falls apart because you fail or medical out.  DO NOT GET MARRIED during all this or you will be compelled to give it up.

Go to university if you can.  If not, learn a trade that pays well and is not too unpleasant to do.  Develop a baseline income stream that is good enough to live on but with enough surplus to pay for flying.  If you have a non-aviation education/income source and build on that, your parents will be much more supportive and you will be able to cruise along, working and flying, enjoying the adventure.

Use the income stream to start on the road.  Private, building hours, Commercial, Instructor and on and on, over a 5-7 year period or so.  You'll be flying Regional Jets long before you are 30 if you just plod along with a patient outlook toward the final goal.  Critical: make sure you make only friends and no enemies along this road.  Unless you are in the US, it is a very small world.

Personally I'm not a big fan of borrowing 60 or 70000 dollars and taking one of those comprehensive college programs.  You come out with 300 hours and a mountain of debt and the entry level flying jobs pay very poorly.  Become an instructor or fly in the bush for a few years, and you will be a infinitely better pilot than the 300 hr college grad.

Comment: +1 for mentioning medical problems.  Get your medical as soon as you start learning to fly so that you'll know where you stand at the outset